# Show that $f'(a)$ exists

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear, prove that $f'(a)$ exists for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

I believe I'm supposed to use the following theorem:

The mapping $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if there exists a linear mapping $L:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-L(h)}{h}=0
\end{equation}

I know it's really basic, but I'm really struggling with this.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is linear,

$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-L(h)}{h}=\frac{f(h)-L(h)}{h}.$$
Take $f=L$ and you'll get the result ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is linear, we let $L-f$. Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-L(h)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f(h)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+h)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0}{h}=0.
\end{aligned}
$$